# JavaFX - Play video as a background

Tags: video, background, javafx

I'm relatively new to JavaFX 2 and I was wondering if it is possible to have a video as an application background instead of a static image. Should I use a `StackPane` and put there the panes? If so, should I make the class `myVideoPlayer` extend the Pane class in order to make it stackable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) and add two children to it:

```
StackPane // scene root
  MediaView     // background video player for your application.
  Pane subclass // your application's main UI content
```

Take a look at the [Oracle JavaFX Media tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm#CMHEJIBA) for information on creating the MediaView and having it display media.

As the video will likely be a different size than your application content, you may need to work out what you want to deal with the size mismatch (e.g. scale the MediaView or  letterbox it or tile it).  Dealing with this issue is currently beyond the scope of this answer.

If you try to set that up and have difficulties, edit your question to add an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Nice! So I should create a StackPane and use it as a root? I mean, in the Java official examples they ever create a Group and put the Nodes to it.

Thanks!

Comment: I got it! The answer to my own question is yes: I created a StackPane as a root, then I added to it the mediaView and a BorderPane. In the latter I have all my UI. Thank you again!